# Android app crash, when stopping a service

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-mediaplayer

In an Android app made to play some audio file in the background, I have the following situation. The app plays the audio as I expect, also keeping playing in the background. The issue I am facing is when I want to stop the service.

I have two buttons on the main activity, one for starting the service and the other one to stop it.

This is the function fired by the START button:

```
fun startHandler(view: View) {
    val audioName = "myAudio"
    val serviceIntent = Intent(this, TheService::class.java)
    serviceIntent.putExtra("name", audioName);
    startForegroundService(serviceIntent)
}
```

This is the function fired by the STOP button:

```
fun stopHandler(view: View) {
    val serviceIntent = Intent(this, TheService::class.java)
    stopService(serviceIntent)
}
```

When I tap the STOP button, the audio stops (as expected), but the app crashes right after (this is not expected).

Here is the onDestroy() function on the service side:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    audioPlayer.stop()
}
```

And the onStartCommand() function on the service side:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    val runnable = Runnable {
        val audioName = intent?.getStringExtra("name")
        val audioID = resources.getIdentifier(audioName,"raw", packageName)
        audioPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, audioID)
        audioPlayer?.setLooping(true)
        audioPlayer.start()
    }

    val thread = Thread(runnable)
    thread.start()

    return START_NOT_STICKY
}
```

Is there any mistake that can be seen in the code above or some place I should look at in order to solve the problem ?

Comment: "but the app crashes right after" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: Seems like you are using a foreground service. Maybe you stop the notification associated with this foreground service before stopping the actual service. This would result in the application crashing since a foreground service can't run without a persistent notification.

Comment: Well the truth is I have no notification as you probably can see in the code I posted. That may be the reason for the problem. I did not find the right way to set a notification and it was OK without (at least up to a point).